# how to keep origin image size in swift ui

Tags: swiftui

I am using KFImage to load images from URLs in swift UI, however, I want to keep the width and height that come with the image from the URL they come in different sizes

```
KFImage(URL(string: egg.logoUrl))
                           .resizable()
                           .fixedSize()
```

I used jetback compose, and I can say that one of the hardest things in swift Ui, is image scaling that requires geometry rendering wherein compose can do it in single function call

Comment: Remove the view modifiers. And you are using too many exclamation marks by the way. If something is supposed to be non-optional declare it non-optional.

Comment: no no noting working

Comment: Actually without `.resizable` and `.fixedSize` it does *keep the width and height that come with the image from the URL*. However you might consider the scaling of the image, if it's @x1, @x2 or @x3.

Comment: ok, is there any way to keep the original size and resize it if it exceed max size

Comment: `.scaleEffect()` scales the original image (0.5 == 50%)